Mongo is going in frozen state: kernel: INFO: task mongod:88453 blocked for more than 122 seconds
I'm encountering an issue where MongoDB goes into a frozen state on my server. After logging into MongoDB, no commands can be executed, and the secondary node does not automatically promote to primary. We had to manually force the secondary to become the primary.
Environment Details:
OS: Amazon Linux 2 (aarch64)
Kernel Version: 5.10.205-195.807.amzn2.aarch64
MongoDB Version: 4.2.18
Please find Error message


dhclient[1337]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 10.20.20.0 port 67 (xid=0x3c87aa13)
dhclient[1337]: DHCPACK from 1.1.1.1 (xid=0x3c87aa13)
NET: dhclient: Locked /run/dhclient/resolv.lock
dhclient[1337]: bound to 1.1.1.1 -- renewal in 1726 seconds.
ec2net: [get_meta] Querying IMDS for meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/97:4d:545:70:df:03/local-ipv4s
ec2net: [get_meta] Getting token for IMDSv2.
ec2net: [get_meta] Trying to get http://1.1.1.1/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/97:4d:545:70:df:03/local-ipv4s
ec2net: [remove_aliases] Removing aliases of eth0
kernel: INFO: task mongod:88453 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
kernel:      Not tainted 5.10.205-195.807.amzn2.aarch64 #1
kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
kernel: task:mongod          state:D stack:    0 pid:88453 ppid:     1 flags:0x00000200
kernel: Call trace:
kernel: __switch_to+0x7c/0xa0
kernel: __schedule+0x28c/0x718
kernel: schedule+0x4c/0xcc
kernel: rwsem_down_write_slowpath+0x334/0x75c
kernel: down_write+0x84/0x98
kernel: xfs_ilock+0x110/0x120
kernel: xfs_file_buffered_aio_write+0x88/0x338
kernel: xfs_file_write_iter+0xb8/0x100
kernel: new_sync_write+0xf0/0x18c
kernel: vfs_write+0x21c/0x2b0
kernel: ksys_pwrite64+0x78/0xb8
kernel: __arm64_sys_pwrite64+0x24/0x2c
kernel: el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x84/0x240
kernel: do_el0_svc+0x28/0x80
kernel: el0_svc+0x1c/0x28
kernel: el0_sync_handler+0x94/0x120
kernel: INFO: task WTOplog.lThread:88478 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
kernel:      Not tainted 5.10.205-195.807.amzn2.aarch64 #1
kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
kernel: task:WTOplog.lThread state:D stack:    0 pid:88478 ppid:     1 flags:0x00000208



Does anyone help to figure out causing this or how to resolve it?
